# an invalid or illegal selector was specified error on protractor angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-selectors, protractor

so I've been using protractor as my e2e test angularjs component, and I've been facing this issue..

so I've got an html markup like this

```
 <div class="item">
       <div class="item-grid">grid A</div>
       <div class="item-actions">
           <input type="image" class="item-action-image" title="info" src="images/icons/system-info.png">
           <input type="image" class="item-action-image" title="event" src="images/icons/system-event.png">
       </div>
    </div>
<div class="item">
       <div class="item-grid">grid B</div>
       <div class="item-actions">
           <input type="image" class="item-action-image" title="info" src="images/icons/system-info.png">
           <input type="image" class="item-action-image" title="event" src="images/icons/system-event.png">
       </div>
    </div>
```

let's say if one of the input typed image above was clicked, there will be an information modal coming up to display the information.

so I want to create a scenario on protractor to simulate those..

the scenario would be

```
it("should've display grid information datas", function() {

        element(by.css(".item:eq(0) > .item-actions > input[title='info']")).click();

        browser.waitForAngular();

  });
```

logical explanation for the above code is the protractor would select the first `'.item'` element then click the `'input[title="info"]'` inside it right ?

but instead I got this error

```
InvalidSelectorError: The given selector .item:eq(0) > .item-actions > input[title='info'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

therefore I've been stuck since I'm new to using protractor.. is there anybody that could help me solve this issue ?

Comment: `:eq(0)` isn't CSS AFAIK

Comment: @Quentin: [It is a jquery selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq/), unavailable in css files. (I have no idea if protractor supports those...)

Comment: Try just `.item > .item-actions > input[title='info']")` That should give you the input under the first `.item`

Comment: @JuanMendes I've tried the one that you suggested, unfortunately the one that is being clicked is not the first element :(

Comment: @Cerbrus: Protractor uses WebDriver, so it's unlikely that it supports jQuery selectors.

Comment: @BoltClock ah I see now.. is there any solution that could you provide about this ?

Comment: @user3860691 If you show the HTML around `.item`, we can help using [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) You can try `.item:nth-child(1) > .item-actions > input[title='info']")`

Comment: @JuanMendes it says  `NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".item:nth-child(1) > .item-actions > input[title='info']")` :(

Comment: That means there are elements appearing before the first `.item` in the parent element. Can you show the entire contents of the parent element?

Comment: @JuanMendes it's done! I have to use `browser.waitForAngular()` first apparently thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can chain ElementFinders. For example:

```
$$('.item')
  .get(1)
  .$('input[title=info]')
  .click();
```

Or

```
element.all(by.css('.item'))
  .get(1)
  .element(by.css('input[title=info]')
  .click();
```

Notice that `$$('.abc')` is the same as `element.all(by.css('.abc'))` and `$('.abc')` is the same as `element(by.css('.abc'))`